# React-native load dependency only for one platform (android or ios)

Tags: react-native, dependency-management

I'm working on a project where it is needed to add an specific dependency for a feature on iOS and i would like to avoid to include this library in the android bundle. Is it possible? It isn´t a response to change the name of the android or ios project and run 'react-native link' ;)

The library is [react-native-text-detector](https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-text-detector)

Comment: for the native library, you can  load it alone for android or ios. for js library there is no solution.

Comment: you should give more details, such as what library.

Comment: the library is [react-native-text-detector](https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-text-detector). Is a js library :(

Comment: it is not a pure js library, you can find the same native ios library, and write js bridge module  by yourself

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but you could do something like

```
let textDetector;

if(Platform.OS === "ios"){
    textDetector = require("react-native-text-detector");
}
```

And then when you use it just make sure to check if it is not undefined